# which one is correct of these options?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

for the following set of simultaneous equations:  $ 1.5x-0.5y=2 $ ; $4x+2y+9z=9$ ; $ 7x+y+5z=10 $

1. the solution is unique
2. infinitely many solutions exist
3. the equations are not compatible
4. finite number of multiple solutions exist

I hope the answer will be 3, is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- (4) can not be true since we're talking about a linear system
- $det\begin{pmatrix}1.5&-0.5&0\\4&2&9\\7&1&5\end{pmatrix}\neq0$ thus it's (1)

Comment: your system is contradictous. $2\neq1$

Comment: (devide the second equation by 2, assume there is a solution et voilà)

Comment: call it whatever you like, still there is no *finite* number of *multiple* (minimum 2) solutions to any linear system in a vector space with a field of characteristic zero.

Comment: I comment in your words"(4) can not be true since we're talking about a linear system". I also quote "Incompatible system: if the system hasn’t got a solution, then the straight lines are parallel". fine discussion thank you

Comment: 4 states *solutions exist* and *they are more than 1* and they are *finite* fine discussion, you are welcome.

Comment: What a bad inattention? it is my mistake, i really sorry?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is unique since the determinant is not zero.
$$|A|=|\pmatrix{1.5 &-.5 &0\\
4& 2& 9\\
7 &1 &5}
|= -20.0$$

Comment: alright, thanks a lot